# How to change S3 object owner while using CodeDeploy, to upload objects, from a different AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

### the setup

I have a codepipeline set up in account B and it attempts to deploy objects to S3 in account A. The build is successful, and the artifacts are deployed successfully to S3 in account A.

### the problem

When I inspect the objects on account A, the owner is account B. This is problematic because this bucket is actually where I host a public site and according to AWS' rules for public sites hosted in S3, **The AWS account that owns the bucket must also own the object.**

### the question

How can I either modify the owner when CodeDeploy in account B deploys to account A's S3 bucket, or make it so that anything uploaded to the S3 bucket is owned by account A?